# Fetch Data From SQLite Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to fetch my registered user data from SQLite rather then the web server in my android application. I want when the registered user of my application login with their Id and password.Then the existing data related to them should be fetch and display in the application. Please guide me how can I do this.
 I have created the two Java file for I created the SQLite database and inserting value into them.

**Login.Java**

Log in page for the registered user to log in application with their own account id and password.only the registered user can log in . I have used the Json parsing concept in my application to parse and interchange my data with web services.

**Password.java** 
    Following is the content of Database class

```
           I t is the second class which include the connectivity part for log in page

            public class PasswordDB

            {
                EditText edittext;
                 TextView tv;
                private static final  String DATABASE_NAME = "DGC.db";
                private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
                static final String TABLE_NAME = "Drivers";
                private static Context context;
                static SQLiteDatabase db;

                private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

               //insertion of the value into table//
                private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (mfname,msname,mun,mstreet,msuburb,mstate,mpostcode,mlicense,mid,mmobile,memail,mimagelicense,mauthcard,mpic) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                protected static final String enternpw = null;
                public PasswordDB(Context context) {
                PasswordDB.context = context;
                OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(PasswordDB.context);
                PasswordDB.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                this.insertStmt = PasswordDB.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
                }

                public long insert(String mfname,String msname,String mun,String mstreet,String msuburb,String mstate,String mpostcode,String mlicense,String mid,String mmobile,String memail,byte[] mimagelicense,byte[] mauthcard,byte[] mpic ) {
                this.insertStmt.bindString(1, mfname);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(2, msname);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(3, mun);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(4, mstreet);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(5, msuburb);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(6, mstate);
             //   this.insertStmt.bindString(7, mpassword);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(7, mpostcode);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(8, mlicense);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(9, mid);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(10, mmobile);
                this.insertStmt.bindString(11, memail);
                this.insertStmt.bindBlob(12, mimagelicense);
                this.insertStmt.bindBlob(13, mauthcard);
                this.insertStmt.bindBlob(14, mpic);
                return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
                }


                public void deleteAll() {
                db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
                }

                public List<String[]> selectAll()
                {
                List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id","mfname","msname","mun","mstreet","msuburb","mstate","mpassword","mconfirm_password","mpostcode","mlicense","mid","mmobile","memail","mimagelicense","mauthcard","mpic" }, null, null, null, null, "memail asc");
                int x=0;
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                   do {
                    String[] b1=new String[]{cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),
                            cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
                            cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),cursor.getString(11),cursor.getString(12),cursor.getString(13),cursor.getString(14),cursor.getString(15)};
                    list.add(b1);
                    x=x+1;
                   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                   cursor.close();
                }
                cursor.close();
                return list;
               }





             //method to delete the value from table//
               public void delete(int rowId) {
                db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
               }

               private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
                OpenHelper(Context context) {
                     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mfname TEXT, msname TEXT,mun TEXT,mstreet TEXT,msuburb TEXT,mstate TEXT,mpassword TEXT,mconfirm_password TEXT,mpostcode TEXT,mlicense TEXT,mid TEXT,mmobile TEXT,memail TEXT,mimagelicense BLOB,mauthcard BLOB,mpic BLOB)");
                }

                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
                    {
                     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                     onCreate(db);
                }
               }
            //Database Fetching//
               public ArrayList getAllDriversDetail()
               {
                   Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("Select * from TutorialsPoint",null);
                   resultSet.moveToFirst();
                   String username = resultSet.getString(1);
                   String password = resultSet.getString(2);
                return null;
               }

            private SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            public Cursor rawQuery(String selectQuery, Object object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
            public static PasswordDB getDBAdapterInstance(ViewData viewPassword) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
            public Object getenternpw() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
            public static Cursor getSinlgeEntry() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Cursor cur =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE_NAME, null);
                // colName1+"='"+name+"'" ->  wherclause
                System.out.println("Record count are "+cur.getCount());
                return cur; 

            }

            public static void close() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            public PasswordDB open() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }


            }
```

Comment: Your code already has functions to fetch data. What is the specific problem with them?

Comment: I want to fetch the data on my update profile page.but I don't know how to pass the reference of update profile page to my password database page.

Comment: Just create the SQLiteDatabase object in update profile page and open the database to read and call fetch function.